# Adjusting location of unknown text with rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have an array of strings, example is below but normally, I will read the strings from a JSON file and have no knowledge of their contents.

```
let SNPJSON:[String] = ["really long text 1","really long text 2",
      "really long text 3","really long text 4","really long text 5",
      "really long text 6","really long text 7","really long text 8"]
```

I want to plot these on a circle by attaching lines, see image.

[image: rotating text around an ellipse]  when theta is past pi/2 I need to move the string, otherwise it will be clobbered by the drawing.

I'm not using UIlabels but
`s.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: x + 0.0 , y: y - fontSize*1.5 ), withAttributes: attributes)`

1. How to get the positional offset of an unknown string? Without counting up characters and using font properties.
2. Is there a way to do this without an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Using this will get height and width of bounding box of string
`sizeWithAttributes(attributes)`

Then

`xOffset = -s.sizeWithAttributes(attributes).width`

and 
`drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: x + xOffset , y: y + yOffset ), withAttributes: attributes)`

[image]